# place an item to the bottom based a condition during sort

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
  [ {'id': 3, 'count': 9}, {'id': 4,'count': null}, {'id':5,'count':4}]
```

Basically, the order should be count but if count is null, the item(s) should be placed to the bottom of the sort. I tried the following but it is not working. The above should give (for asc):

```
  {'id': 3, 'count': 9}
  {'id':5,'count':4}
  {'id': 4,'count': null}
```

When descending:

```
  {'id': 5, 'count': 4}
  {'id':3,'count':9}
  {'id': 4,'count': null}
```

Code

```
let sortValue = -1; //asc
let direction = 'asc';

if (direction != "asc") {
  sortValue = 1;
}

objArr.sort(function(a: Item, b: Item) {

      const aCount  = a['count'] ;
      const bCount  = b['count'];

      if ( aCount == null){
        return -1;
      }

      if ( bCount == null){
        return -1;
      }

      return aCount>bCount? -1 * sortValue : aCount<bCount ? sortValue : 0;
```

Comment: you return `-1` regardless of which number is null?

Comment: hey @Bravo that was how I understood pushing them to the bottom can be achieved. But basically, if a count is null, the item should be at the bottom. Basically all items with count null should be placed at the bottom of the list. I assumed returning -1 would push the item to go down in the list i guess i am wrong

Comment: you've tagged this question javascript but the code you pasted looks like typescript

Comment: please add thg results of sorting for *asc* and *desc*. where should `null` go in this cases?

Comment: I think the fact that you are returning -1 regardless of whether aCount or bCount is null is breaking the sort. How can the algorithm move nulls to the bottom if the function returns the same value regardless of whether null is the first or the second value?

Comment: @NinaScholz: see my update. But regardless of asc or desc, all count==null items should be at the bottom of the sort.

Comment: btw, your *asc* sort violates the usual understanding of ascending and your *desc* as well. usually if the smaller value is at top and the greater value is at the bottom, this order is calles ascending, as the value grows over the following items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always want a `null` value to be at the bottom then return `1` when `a` is null and `-1` when `b` is null.

```js
function sort(array, sortValue) {
    return array.sort(function ({ count: a }, { count: b }) {
        if (a === null) return 1;
        if (b === null) return -1;
        return (b - a) * sortValue;
    });
}

var array = [{ id: 3, count: 9 }, { id: 4, count: null }, { id: 5, count: 4 }];

console.log(sort(array, -1));
console.log(sort(array, 1));
```

Comment: what is with two null items at the same time?

Comment: @NinaScholz Does that matter? They are both going to be placed at the bottom, I don't think that the order of the two null values matters

Answer (score 1):

You could check for `null` and take the result of the check as sort order.

```js
function sort(array, order = 'asc') {
    var factor = order === 'desc' || -1;
    return array.sort(({ count: a }, { count: b }) => 
        (a === null) - (b === null) || // move null to bottom
        factor * (a - b)               // sort by numerical value
    );
}

var array = [{ id: 3, count: 9 }, { id: 4, count: null }, { id: 5, count: 4 }];

console.log(sort(array));
console.log(sort(array, 'desc'));
```

Comment: Think OP wanted null at the bottom even during `desc`.

Comment: @Nina Scholz: works for asc but not for desc as Jamiec has said. Still thanks.

Comment: this results in `9,4,null` and `null,9,4` - always descending, and null ends up at the top

Comment: @NieSelam, why do you need a sort order? what should happenwith that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define all the cases for return values `-1`, `0` and `1` in order for the `.sort()` to work properly:

```
let direction = 'asc';

objArr.sort((a, b) => {

  if (a.count === null && b.count === null) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (a.count === null) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (b.count=== null) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Ascending direction
  if (direction === 'asc') {
    return a.count - b.count;
  }

  // Descending direction
  return b.count - a.count;
}
```